# Jvectormap show div onRegionClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

Hi I am currently trying to use the Jvectormap plugin which i have found to be really good, however i cannot create this little bit of functionality which would make it amazing...

What i need is when you click on a region text to appear in a predefined div on the right hand side. 
[image]

As you can see in the image i want when you click on United kingdom text to show in the black box on the right hand side.

However all i have managed to do is make the region a link.

Here is a link http://s453688288.websitehome.co.uk/wndirect/destination.php

Here is my code

```
<p>Click on the links below to see some key stats regarding eCommerce in that country.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="green-band">
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">  
  <button id="focus-eu">Focus on Europe</button>
  </div>
  <div class="three columns">  
  <button id="focus-us">Focus on USA</button>
  </div>
  <div class="three columns">  
  <button id="focus-au">Focus on Australia</button>
  </div>
  <div class="three columns">  
  <button id="focus-home">Return to the initial state</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div><!-- end green band -->

<div id="map1">

<div class="info-box"><h3 class="white">Ecommerce info</h3></div>

<div class="footer-illustration-map"></div>

</div><!-- end #map1 -->


<? include("inc/footer.php") ?>

<!-- map functionality-->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="maps/jquery-jvectormap.css"/>
  <script src="maps/jquery-jvectormap.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/jquery-mousewheel.js"></script>

  <script src="maps/lib/jvectormap.js"></script>

  <script src="maps/lib/abstract-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/abstract-canvas-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/abstract-shape-element.js"></script>

  <script src="maps/lib/svg-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/svg-group-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/svg-canvas-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/svg-shape-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/svg-path-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/svg-circle-element.js"></script>

  <script src="maps/lib/vml-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/vml-group-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/vml-canvas-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/vml-shape-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/vml-path-element.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/vml-circle-element.js"></script>

  <script src="maps/lib/vector-canvas.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/simple-scale.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/numeric-scale.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/ordinal-scale.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/color-scale.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/data-series.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/proj.js"></script>
  <script src="maps/lib/world-map.js"></script>

  <script src="maps/tests/assets/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>

 <script>


    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function(){
      var $ = jQuery;

      $('#focus-au').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', 'AU');
      });
      $('#focus-us').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', 3, 0.1, 0.4);
      });
      $('#focus-eu').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', 3, 0.5, 0.3);
      });
      $('#focus-home').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', 1, 0, 0);
      });
      $('#map1').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',

        focusOn: {
          x: 0.5,
          y: 0.5,
          scale: 1
        },

        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',

        onRegionClick: function(event, code){
                        if (code == "GB") {window.location = '#reach'}
                        if (code == "US") {label.text('Bears, vodka, balalaika');}
                        if (code == "DE") {window.location = '/url4'}
                        if (code == "IE") {window.location = '/url5'}
},

        series: {

          regions: [{
            scale: ['#A6CDD4', '#669ca5'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
            values: {
              "GL": 0,
              "AF": 0,
              "AL": 0,
              "DZ": 0,
              "AO": 0,
              "AG": 0,
              "AR": 0,
              "AM": 0,
              "AU": 1,
              "AT": 1,
              "AZ": 0,
              "BS": 0,
              "BH": 0,
              "BD": 0,
              "BB": 0,
              "BY": 0,
              "BE": 0,
              "BZ": 0,
              "BJ": 0,
              "BT": 0,
              "BO": 0,
              "BA": 0,
              "BW": 0,
              "BR": 0,
              "BN": 0,
              "BG": 0,
              "BF": 0,
              "BI": 0,
              "KH": 0,
              "CM": 0,
              "CA": 1,
              "CV": 0,
              "CF": 0,
              "TD": 0,
              "CL": 0,
              "CN": 0,
              "CO": 0,
              "KM": 0,
              "CD": 0,
              "CG": 0,
              "CR": 0,
              "CI": 0,
              "HR": 0,
              "CY": 1,
              "CZ": 1,
              "DK": 0,
              "DJ": 0,
              "DM": 0,
              "DO": 0,
              "EC": 0,
              "EG": 0,
              "SV": 0,
              "GQ": 0,
              "ER": 0,
              "EE": 1,
              "ET": 0,
              "FJ": 0,
              "FI": 0,
              "FR": 1,
              "GA": 0,
              "GM": 0,
              "GE": 0,
              "DE": 1,
              "GH": 0,
              "GR": 0,
              "GD": 0,
              "GT": 0,
              "GN": 0,
              "GW": 0,
              "GY": 0,
              "HT": 0,
              "HN": 0,
              "HK": 0,
              "HU": 1,
              "IS": 0,
              "IN": 0,
              "ID": 0,
              "IR": 0,
              "IQ": 0,
              "IE": 1,
              "IL": 0,
              "IT": 1,
              "JM": 0,
              "JP": 0,
              "JO": 0,
              "KZ": 0,
              "KE": 0,
              "KI": 0,
              "KR": 0,
              "KW": 0,
              "KG": 0,
              "LA": 0,
              "LV": 0,
              "LB": 0,
              "LS": 0,
              "LR": 0,
              "LY": 0,
              "LT": 0,
              "LU": 1,
              "MK": 0,
              "MG": 0,
              "MW": 0,
              "MY": 0,
              "MV": 0,
              "ML": 0,
              "MT": 0,
              "MR": 0,
              "MU": 0,
              "MX": 0,
              "MD": 0,
              "MN": 0,
              "ME": 0,
              "MA": 0,
              "MZ": 0,
              "MM": 0,
              "NA": 0,
              "NP": 0,
              "NL": 1,
              "NZ": 1,
              "NI": 0,
              "NE": 0,
              "NG": 0,
              "NO": 0,
              "OM": 0,
              "PK": 0,
              "PA": 0,
              "PG": 0,
              "PY": 0,
              "PE": 0,
              "PH": 0,
              "PL": 1,
              "PT": 1,
              "QA": 0,
              "RO": 1,
              "RU": 0,
              "RW": 0,
              "WS": 0,
              "ST": 0,
              "SA": 0,
              "SN": 0,
              "RS": 0,
              "SC": 0,
              "SL": 0,
              "SG": 0,
              "SK": 0,
              "SI": 0,
              "SB": 0,
              "ZA": 0,
              "ES": 1,
              "LK": 0,
              "KN": 0,
              "LC": 1,
              "VC": 0,
              "SD": 0,
              "SR": 0,
              "SZ": 0,
              "SE": 0,
              "CH": 1,
              "SY": 0,
              "TW": 0,
              "TJ": 0,
              "TZ": 0,
              "TH": 0,
              "TL": 0,
              "TG": 0,
              "TO": 0,
              "TT": 0,
              "TN": 0,
              "TR": 0,
              "TM": 0,
              "UG": 0,
              "UA": 0,
              "AE": 0,
              "GB": 1,
              "US": 1,
              "UY": 0,
              "UZ": 0,
              "VU": 0,
              "VE": 0,
              "VN": 0,
              "YE": 0,
              "ZM": 0,
              "ZW": 0,
            }
          }]
        }
      });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the vectorMap `mapObject`, and assign it to a variable:

```
var map = $('#map1').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

After which, you can access a method called `getRegionName()`, passing it the `code`.

Then just append that to your `<div>`:

```
onRegionClick: function(event, code) {
  var map = $('#map1').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
  $('.info-box').append('<span>' + map.getRegionName(code) + '</span>');
}
```

(Where `.info-box` is the `class` of the `<div>` you want to append to)

**[Check out this jVectorMap commit](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/commit/98c3d6d0655e88309afe9e5a40e392a9c58275c5)**

Comment: Hi thanks, that worked really well. However is their a way in which we can clear the old name when you click on another region. because at the moment the text just keeps replicating under the old text which will end up with a massive list of names.

Comment: Yeah, just use `.html()` instead of `.append()` to overwrite the contents of the `<div>`